# Python multiprocessing code running slower than single threaded one

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pymssql

The Python Multiprocessing performance on my i7 7700HQ is significantly slower than non-parallel one.

While planning to parallelize my Select and Update code for my single table database in mssql, I tried to first parallelize a simple code. The program simply prints multiples of the argument.
I tried single-threaded, multi-process with Process object and also with Pool object. Single threaded always performed best.

```py
import time

def foobar(a):
    for i in range(1,10000):
        print(a*i)
    return
if __name__ == "__main__":
   Tthreading = time.clock()
    p1= Process(target= foobar, args=(3,))
    p2 = Process(target= foobar, args= (2,))
    p3 = Process(target= foobar, args= (4,))
    p4 = Process(target=foobar, args=(123,))

    allprocess.start

    allprocess.join

    print(time.clock() - Tthreading)

    #Single-threaded
    Tsingle = time.clock()
    foobar(3)
    foobar(2)
    foobar(4)
    foobar(123)
    print(time.clock() - Tsingle)
```

I expected the multi-process to be much faster since there are no shared resources(no functions, variables that need to be accessed between threads) and IPC.

Single Threaded time: 0.32s

Multi-Process time: 0.53s

Comment: You're sharing stdout...

Comment: removing print and simplt doing 'a*i' didn't help parallel code to get faster than non-parallel

Comment: user higher and higher values for `range` and you will see that multiprocessing begins to win. There is always overhead to starting and joining the processes. Rather a lot.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes!. It changed it to a double loop and it shows its magic, amazing. Can I know one thing? do the other functions that the 'target' Process function uses inside itself count as a shared resource? Should I have a class and then make a process for each object to overcome this? Any other methods? 
Thanks you!

Comment: No, there are two separate python processes with independent state, copies of the memory segments of the parent process (this is a factor in the overhead). They are not threads.

Comment: So, even the functions not passed through target will have  multiple copies? I thought those functions as a shared resource.

Comment: Again, **the entire process is copied**. Not just the functions, all state. The processes *do not share state*. Sharing state is not trivial using multiprocessing, although, various tools are provided to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is one important shared resource in your example, your monitor (or `stdout`).

`print` is a relatively slow operation (compared to CPU cycles...), and it causes contention between your proccesses.

Benchmarking parallel work correctly is a tough task, it is affected by the great many factors and features of a CPU (e.g. cache).

Try to replace your workload with one that is very suited for multiprocessing (e.g. working in a parallel on different parts of an array, matrix multiplication...)

One more important thing: spawning the new processes also takes time, and for it to pay off the work done in each process needs to be significant.
If you increase your loop's range a little bit, the difference should be in favor of the Multi-process version:

```py
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def foobar(a):
    for i in range(1,10000000):
        a*i
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Tthreading = time.time()
    p1= Process(target= foobar, args=(3,))
    p2 = Process(target= foobar, args= (2,))
    p3 = Process(target= foobar, args= (4,))
    p4 = Process(target=foobar, args=(123,))

    allprocess = [p1,p2,p3,p4]
    for p in allprocess:
        p.start()

    for p in allprocess:
        p.join()

    print(time.time() - Tthreading)

    #Single-threaded
    Tsingle = time.time()
    foobar(3)
    foobar(2)
    foobar(4)
    foobar(123)
    print(time.time() - Tsingle)
```

on my machine this outputs:

> 0.44509196281433105
>
> 1.3775699138641357

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Now, after changing the foobar to,
`python
def foobar(a):

    for i in range(1,10000):

        a*i

    return
`
The time reduces dramatically, but single thread is still faster.

Single-Threaded Time: 0.004s
Multi-threaded: 0.22s

Comment: you have the extra time of spawning the new processes, it is also kind of a heavy duty operation.

Comment: Try doing heavier work in foobar, something that will take a few seconds rather than few millis, the difference should balance in favor of the multi-process solution

Comment: I'm on my phone, in about 1h I'll be in front of a laptop and could help provide an example

Comment: Thank you Adam.Er8 !! An example will be really helpful

Comment: Also, do the other functions that the 'target' Process function uses inside itself count as a shared resource? Should I have a class and then make a process for each object to overcome this? Any other methods?

Comment: No, it is not a shared resource, code resides in the 'text' segment of memory and can be read simultaneously without any problem.

Comment: thinking of this, to make your example is valid, to make it run longer we just need to increase the loop's `range` (add 3-4 more zeroes...), I'm adding it:

Comment: Thank you so much for the info! This is such a helpful community. Thank you!